# Given XElement - Find node text by node name

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, xelement, xmlnode

I have loaded an XML document into an `XElement`

It looks a little like this:

```
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-03-14T05:31:16" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-AU">
<my:header>
    <my:item1></my:item1>
    <my:item2></my:item2>
    <my:item3></my:item3>
</my:header>
<my:header2>
    <my:title1>Blah</my:title1>
    <my:title2>Zlib</my:title2>
    <my:title3>Bleep</my:title3>
</my:header2>
```

All I want to do, is search for the "node text" (i.e. "Blah", "Zlib" or "Bleep") given input "node name" (i.e. "title1", "title2", "title3")

I have tried `xeData.Attribute("title1")` and `xeData.Element("title1")` and also various linq statements without success.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the namespace of the "title" elements.  Try this instead:

```
string titleText = xeData.Element(XName.Get("title1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-03-14T05:31:16")).Value;
```

I'm assuming here that xeData is the "header" element -- if it's not, you'll have to figure out how to select that first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find or create nodes in a namespace it helps using `XNamespace` objects which are part of the LINQ to XML.
Here is an example:

```
    XElement myFields = XElement.Load("../../XMLFile3.xml");
    XNamespace my = myFields.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("my");
    Console.WriteLine(myFields.Element(my + "header2").Element(my + "title1").Value);
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387042.aspx.